# Evaluating shell commands in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file called `foo.txt` with contents:

```
Fusce porttitor tortor nisl, eu commodo mi mattis eu. Ut sodales, 
nulla in facilisis ultrices, diam ante dapibus mi, at mollis 
arcu ante vitae lectus. Aenean vitae bibendum massa, in varius est. 
`cat baz.txt`
Mauris quis turpis venenatis, ultrices ipsum ac, mollis tellus.
```

I would like a shell command that I can invoke using

```
./cmd.sh foo.txt
```

that replaces each `` ` ``-quoted shell command with the result of evaluating that command. How can this be done (ideally using Bash)?

As a bonus: I would like this to happen recursively. That is, if my `baz.txt` file contains further `` ` ``-quoted shell commands, I would like those to be evaluated too.

Comment: Any attempts yourself ?

Comment: It should be possible by using grep to detect lines containing 2 `\` `, sed to split them, eval to execute `\` `-ed commands, and it should even be possible to do that recursively by noting the command with `PROG=$0`. But honestly, I think I would really deserve a real program.

Comment: @123 nothing that would add to the clarity of the question.

Comment: @SergeBallesta thanks. What do you mean by you deserve a real program? I've phrased my question in an abstracted form so that it's useful to other readers in the future, but my use-case is basically the same.

Comment: I meant a program written in C, C++, Java, Python or whatever. IMHO what you need is beyond what can be done in pure shell.

Comment: Allowing arbitrary executable code in input data is a terrible idea from a security standpoint. Instead, format your input with something recognizable like `...in various est [%include baz.txt] Mauris`, which your program can interpret as a request to insert a file. Note that this is different from simply asking your program to execute whatever arbitrary code appears between backticks. (Yes, you essentially need to write an interpreter for a markup language.)

Answer (score 0):

The security worries expressed by @chepner notwithstanding, I found the following `awk` solution. It's not recursive, but it'll do.

```
awk -F"\"" '
$1=="SHELL " && NF>=2 {
   system($2)
   next
}
{print}' "$@"
```

The script looks for lines in the file of the form `SHELL "foo"`, and replaces such lines with the result of executing `"foo"`.